# Simple String matching in java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement simple String matching. The algorithm should return 1 if the  *source* String contains the *pattern* String. I cannot understand why it is returning -1 on the following inputs

```
    String source = "aababba";
    String pattern = "abba";
```

Here is my implementation:

```
public static int findMatch(String source, String pattern)
{
    int j = 0,  pos = -1;
    boolean matched = false;

    if(source.length() < pattern.length())
        return -1;


    for(int i = 0; i < (source.length() - pattern.length()); i++)
    {
        if(source.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j))
            j++;
        else
            j = 0;
        if(j == pattern.length())
        {
            matched = true;
            break;
        }           
    }

    if(matched)
        return 1;       
    return -1;  
}
```

**EDIT:**
As many of you suggested, the culprit was the for loop. 
I should have made it as follows. The rest of the code is the same. Other solutions are also possible as shown in the answers.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (source.length() - pattern.length()); i++)
    {
        if(source.charAt(i+j) == pattern.charAt(j))
        {
```

Comment: A good time to use your debugger to debug your code.

Comment: Why you use `(source.length() - pattern.length())` in `for` loop?

Comment: @MaximShoustin because it's no use checking the last three characters of the string if you are trying to match a 4-character pattern. It's a good idea, I just think the implementation is not exactly correct.

Comment: This isn't very clear on what your algorithm is intended to do. *Why* should it return `1` instead of `-1`? Is it because source contains the pattern? Or does source just have to contain all of the letters of pattern? Or something else?

Comment: To stick with the QA format of this site, you shouldn't edit answers into solutions.  Either post your own answer and accept or accept an existing one and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length of source is 7. Length of pattern is 4. Your statement `i < (source.length() - pattern.length()` will not be true for i > 2 so the loop just does not run "far" enough.

Answer (score 6):

You are only checking three characters

```
source.length() - pattern.length()
```

So `j` will never be equal to `pattern.length`.  You need to check the entire `source`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++)
{
  if(source.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j))
  ...
}
```

---

**Regarding the Solution**

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (source.length() - pattern.length()); i++)
    {
        if(source.charAt(i+j) == pattern.charAt(j))
        {
```

Why have an additional subtraction and addition plus more complicated code when you can just step through the length of source?

Comment: The second characters will match when the pattern occurs. What do you mean?

Comment: This will happen for the first characters. But when i = 4, j will be be 1 and hence b==b.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the intent of the match.  I've removed the irrelevant parts of my answer.

Comment: ...and extended on the relevant part :)

Answer (score 2):

The source of an issue is that you've limited the upper bound of `i` variable by `(source.length() - pattern.length())`. The `for` loop you've written can't check all the characters of `source` string, thus it'll return -1 even for some pairs of strings where it's possible to find a match.
Solution: rewrite the `for` loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [String.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method to check if a string contains the patter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already know the reason why it return wrong. You can try this:

```
j = 0；
while（j <= (source.length() - pattern.length())）{

    for (i = pattern.length(); i >= 0 && pattern[i] == source[i + j]; --i);

    if (i < 0)) {
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
    else j++；
}
```

about string matching, there are many methods, you can use KMP, BM and Sunday and so on, and performance comparation is: KMP < BM < Sunday, you can try these and they are very userful.

Answer (score 0):

By using this statement `(source.length() - pattern.length())` you are looping on the string only on the three first chars of the source. So I will never find the entire pattern.

Try using `pattern.length()` instead, or better try compute the minimal value of both `pattern.length()` and `source.length()`

Comment: Aaannd the third or fourth answer of this kind. Dont read the other answers before posting?

Comment: Yes, you are right I didn't see them, my fault. But on the other hand I offered something else than you, by proposing to compute the shorter length instead of only source length.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume it should return `1` because `"aababba"` contains `"abba"` at the end.

This, from your edit (solution) will return `1`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (source.length() - pattern.length()); i++) {
    if(source.charAt(i+j) == pattern.charAt(j)) {
```

But from my assumption, you should be checking through every letter in `source` so I would use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
    if(source.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j)) {
```

Because why ignore the last bunch of characters?

But maybe I'm just assuming wrong what you want your algorithm to do because from what I've assumed, you could just use:

```
if (source.contains(pattern))
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

Comment: Look at the charAt(i+j) inside the loop. That makes it similar to checking till source.length()

Comment: @Andromeda Ah yes you're right - I missed that. Please remove your downvote. I edited my answer.

Comment: @RossDrew Originally I had said that his edit would still give him the wrong output, but I was mistaken on that point.